# "Scheduled refresh" grayed out

Tags: powerbi

I have problems to refresh data automatically, since "Scheduled refresh" entry is grayed out, btw the gateway seems running ok, as showed into image. Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you apply your gateway settings?

[image]

Comment: How can I check if gateway is configured properly?